# Adding a Windows printer

Tags: printers

I need to add `60 label` printers to my Windows 7 computer, as network printers. They are all the same printer brand `(datamax - O'Neil MP Compact4 MarkII)` using the same driver. Each printer is pre configured with IP address and port.
Of course I can add each printer one by one to my Windows, but does anyone know a way to `script` this into a .bat file or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. If you are adding them as local devices with ports, one of the easiest is to use the built-in vbs scripts on Windows under:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US
```

If you need to create the ports you can do this via prnport.vbs then create the printer using prnmngr.vbs. Both of these commands are very straight forward to use:

```
cscript prnport.vbs -a -r <port name> -h <ip address>
cscript prnmngr.vbs -a -p <printer name> -m <driver name> -r <port name>
```

Putting this into a large batch file is simple.

I do this so often that I built an Excel Workbook to do it for me. This also allows you to select a remote system / server and poll it for what drivers are installed so you don't mis-type that. You can use this to do the actual work or to create you a batch file that you can later modify.

http://www.ballisticecho.com/articles-and-downloads/best-tool-for-printer-creation-excel-vs-print-management-console